# Symfony: How i can run command from controller?

Tags: symfony

I want to run a command from controller but nothing happens.
When I run a command from the console, everything works - the command starts and imports the database.

I would like a command to run after calling the controller.
Below is my controller code. Do I have to define anything else? Routing etc?

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

// Import the required classed
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

/**
* @Route("/api/import")
*/
class ImportController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/upload")
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        $input = new ArrayInput(array(
            'command' => 'app:import-database'
        ));

        $output = new BufferedOutput();

        $application->run($input, $output);

        // return the output
        $content = $output->fetch();

        // Send the output of the console command as response
        return new Response($content);
    }
}
```

Comment: your code seem good, can you give us more details abouts your probleme pls ?

Comment: Running a command from a controller is seldom needed.  Take the functionality you wish to execute out of the command and move it into it's own service.  Then access the service from either the command or the controller as needed.  Plus, an AbstractController typically does not have access to the kernel service.

Comment: I understand that what I have in the command file, I can transfer to the service and execute the command there. How can I throw a message from the service to the controller. Currently my controller is running a command but it doesn't work. Nothing happens. The command is not executed. Do I have to define anything else in the routing?

Answer (score 4):

Try this, by way of example and working in Symfony4.4:

Change

```
class ImportController extends AbstractController
```

to:

```
class ImportController extends Controller
```

Add route: ***config/routes.yaml***

```
import_upload:
  methods: POST
  path: /api/import/upload
  controller: App\ApiBundle\Controller\ImportController::upload
```

Example:

```
use Exception;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

class ImportController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return Response
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function upload(): Response
    {
        $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);
        $input = new ArrayInput(array(
            'command' => 'app:import-database'
        ));
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);
        // return the output
        $content = $output->fetch();
        // Send the output of the console command as response
        return new Response($content);
    }
}
```

Execute a request:

```
 curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8002/api/import/upload' --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

---

> What's the difference between Controller or AbstractController? Not
> much: both are identical, except that AbstractController is more
> restrictive. The `$this->get()` and `$this->container->get()`
> methods don't allow you to access to your own services but only to a
> limited set of services commonly used in controllers (such as
> `twig`, `doctrine`, `session`, etc.)

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/9926

Comment: Thansk. Nope. it does not work. I am using Symfony 5.0
In this release, the Controller must be replaced by the AbstractController